# Узнать точный запускаемый класс | Java

Tags: java

Думаю скриншотами будет понятнее, чуть ниже опишу текстом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю понятно, теперь объясню словами:
У меня есть два класса, Test1 и Test2
В классе Test2 находится метод запуска программы
Класс Test1 наследует Test2, поэтому мы можем его запустить. Моя задача заключается в том, что мне нужно в классе Test2 понять какой класс его запускает.

Типа если я запустил класс Test2, то он выведет Test2, если я запустил другой класс который наследует Test2, то вывести это название ( в моём случае это Test1 ).

Если ты ничего не понял, смотри скриншоты

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В статическом методе Вы не узнаете какой класс использовался для его запуска.

Comment: Мне кажется можно. Может быть я чего-то не понимаю, но в JavaFX то, что я хочу
https://i.imgur.com/6vpJ3N7.png

Comment: Единственный способ решить эту проблему это добавить main в Test1

Comment: Тогда не понимаю как это работает в JavaFX. Класс Application не наследует никого, метода main там нету. Выше мой комментарий со скрином

Comment: В разных фреймворках разные соглашения насчет того, что является точкой входа в приложение. То, что IDE вам отображает треугольничек, — это фича IDE, а не языка Java. Из вопроса не совсем ясно, какую проблему вы хотите решить.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял что это сделать нельзя. Тогда я решил просто собрать все классы которые наследуют Test2 через библиотеку reflections